# Creating simple paint app using Html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to draw circles in HTML canvas and the size of the circle depends, how much user drags the mouse.

But the result I expected is different.I have attached my script file.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',down);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',up);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    var mousePos=getMousePos(canvas,e);
    var posx=mousePos.x;
    var posy=mousePos.y;

    drawCircle(posx,posy,canvas)
});
var md;
function down(){
    md=true;
}

function up(){
    md=false;
}

function getMousePos(canvas,e){

    var pos=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    return  {
        x:e.clientX-pos.left,
        y:e.clientY-pos.top
    }
}


function drawCircle(x,y,canvas){

    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    var radius=x/10;
    if(md){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(100, 75,radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

```css
#myCanvas {width:100%; height:600px}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Right now your snippet does not work, because your canvas doesn't exist. You should add your canvas element to the HTML section of the code snippet.

Comment: Additionally, can you clarify "But the result I expected is different."? What result *did* you expect? Please [edit] this in, or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I have created canvas with canvas tag and id 'myCanvas' in my html file

Comment: What about the other questions that I asked?

Comment: As I drag a circle on a mouse: the size of the circle should increase. This is the expected result.

Comment: That seems to appear what's happening.

Comment: But the code that draws the circle, is getting executed everytime. I don't know where to place that code

Answer (score 0):

When drawing with canvases, you have to remember that you need to clear your canvas, or revert it back to an older state, otherwise your strokes will just keep piling on.

You can read more about canvas states here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/canvas_states.htm

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',down);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',up);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    var mousePos=getMousePos(canvas,e);
    var posx=mousePos.x;
    var posy=mousePos.y;
    drawCircle(posx,posy,canvas)
});
var md;
function down(){
    md=true;
}

function up(){
    md=false;
}

function getMousePos(canvas,e){

    var pos=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    return  {
        x:e.clientX-pos.left,
        y:e.clientY-pos.top
    }
}


function drawCircle(x,y,canvas){

    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var radius=x/10;
    if(md){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(100, 75,radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

```css
#myCanvas {width:100%; height:600px}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that

Comment: Now I should create many circles on every mouse click but now only one circle is getting created!Also when I click on particular circle I need to get print to console that particular circle is clicked.